# How can I pass a variable value from one sub to another

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, variables

I am new to the programming world. I have got the chance to work and develop in a project built with vb.net and asp.net.

In my coding I have stored a value in a variable under one sub `btn_Click()`. I want to use that variable value from another sub - `AddCategory()`. Both are written under same class.

```
Protected Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim sale = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

    Dim SaleID As String = sale

    Core.DB.Insert("insert into survey(id,title, detail) values(@id,@title, @detail);", Core.DB.SIP("title", Title), Core.DB.SIP("detail", Detail), Core.DB.SIP("id", sale))

    Call AddCategory1()

    Response.Redirect("profile.aspx")
End
```

As you can see in the above code the ID value for sale table is a GUID value and I am converting into a string to store it one variable SaleID.

And you can also see I have called `AddCategory1()`. Now I want to pass the value of `SaleID` (string) into `AddCategory()`. And I want to do another insert query to *category* table under `AddCategory()`

```
Private Sub AddQuestionCategory1()

    Core.DB.Insert("insert into SaleCategory(title, detail, saleid) values(@title, @detail, @sid)", Core.DB.SIP("title", CategoryTitle), Core.DB.SIP("detail", CategoryDetail), Core.DB.SIP("sid", sale))

End Sub
```

To be able to do so I have to pass the value stored under the variable `SaleID`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry if I have asked any stupid question. But I am self learner. No one has taught me . So I struggle to understand the very basic things which may seem to you as easy as reading abcd.  But I am still a cave man. I am learning the a,b,c,d now. So I even struggle to spell C A T - cat :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to pass a value to a method (`Sub` or `Function`) is to make it an argument. Set up the method to expect the SaleID as an argument and then call the method with that argument.

```
Private Sub AddCategory1(SaleID as String)
    'You can use SaleID in your code
End Sub
```

Call this sub from your Click handler like this

```
AddCategory1(SaleID)
```

Comment: Note that if you want the sub `AddCategory1()` to be able to change the value of the variable `SaleID`, you would add the keyword `ByRef` in front of the variable in the sub declaration as such: `Private Sub AddCategory1(ByRef SaleID As String)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. I did not know that.